# How to add a struct to a vector from another class?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am student, and I am trying to build a project. My program is throwing an error while accessing the vector. The size of the vector is 1, but when I call RenderQueue.front it throws an error:

> front() called on empty vector.

My code is below:

global.h

```
struct RenderStruct {
    std::function<void()> testfunction1;
    std::function<void()> testfunction2;
};
static std::vector<RenderStruct> RenderQueue;
```

Test.h

```
class test
{
public:
    static void add_to_queue();
};
```

Test.cpp

```
void test::add_to_queue()
{
        std::function<void()> testfunction1 = [&]()
        {
            std::cout << "First Function Working" << std::endl;
        };
        std::function<void()> testfunction2 = [&]()
        {
            std::cout << "Second Function Working" << std::endl;
        };
        RenderQueue.push_back({testfunction1, testfunction2}); 
};
```

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    test::add_to_queue();
    auto front = RenderQueue.front();

    front.testfunction();
    front.testfunction2();
};
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, but I also had to make a few changes to get the code to compile. Odds are I accidentally fixed your bug while getting the program running.

Comment: Also couldn't reproduce. Note: `front.testfunction();` s/b `front.testfunction1();`

Comment: Consider manufacturing a [mre]. If making the MRE doesn't end early with you spotting and fixing the bug, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: Works fine for me when `front.testfunction()` -> `front.testfunction1()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static linkage variables are not shared between compilation units (cpp files).

Make your variable non static, mark it as extern, then export it from one cpp file (by declaring it without extern there).

Comment: And there we go. I accidentally fixed the bug when building my test.

Comment: The lesson here is don't use global variables then you don't need to worry about linkage types